# Question about the conformal map in the dirchlet problem(Stein and Shakarchi)

Tags: complex-analysis

The direchlet problem on a strip is given as:
[image: page1].
For a more general Dirichlet problem, we have the following paragraph from Stein and Shakarchi:
[image: page2]
[image: page3]
My questions are:

1. We solve the problem by taking the strip to a disc with a conformal map. Shouldn't the function F, go from $\Omega \to D$?  Instead Shakarchi says $D \to \Omega$.
2. Also why is the symbol $\partial \Omega$ used to signify the boundary.
3. What is the Poisson integral formula give - Does it give the solution to the boundary value problem?

I would appreciate some answers. I am self-studying stein and shakarchi.

Answer (score 1):

$1.\,\,$  $F$ goes from the disc to $\Omega$ and $F^{-1}$ goes from $\Omega$ to the disc.

$2.\,\,$  We need some symbol to signify the boundary.  Is your complaint that this is overloaded because the symbol is also used for partial derivative?  The meaning is clear from the context.

$3.\,\,$  Yes, the Poisson integral formula gives the solution on the disc to the Dirichlet problem.  See Stein and Shacharchi, **Princeton Lectures in Analysis Volume II (Complex Analysis)**, Chapter 2, Problem 12, pp. 66 and 67.

$\underline{\texttt{UPDATE}} \text{ (further discussion on 1.)}$

If $F:\mathbb{D}\to\Omega$
then $\tilde{f}=f\circ F$ is defined on the circle (the boundary of the disc).  We can then solve for $\tilde{u}$ inside the disc, and then the solution in the strip is given by $u=\tilde{u} \circ F^{-1}.$

It turns out we need both $F$ and $F^{-1}$, so if you want to switch their roles, I guess it is okay, just notation, but since you are following the book, why not stick to the notation that is there.

Comment: Thank you! But F is taking the strip to the disc - that is the source of my question. Should'nt it go from $\Omega \to D$? As far as #2, yes that is my complaint! it creates ambiguity.

Comment: Updated the answer to try and address 1.  Nothing more to say about 2., other than, yes, okay.  What symbol do you want to use?  A "B" or a fancy "B" for boundary.  The letter B is also used sometimes in other contexts $\cdots$.

Comment: @curious_analyst In some sense, that notation is very suggestive. If I had to guess, partial notation comes from Stokes' theorem and the connection between integrals on the boundary and integrals on the interior.